# how to mix 100+ pictures with python pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Now I'm trying to mix 100+ pictures to one pic(like .png) with pillow(fork PIL)
And I know "PIL.Image.blend(im1, im2, alpha)" can fix all pictures ,however the picture's color was too light.
I want to fix the 100+ pictures **with the color**, **not the transparency**(alpha).
I know another API for fix is "PIL.Image.composite(image1, image2, mask)"
but when using it, it tell something was wrong.

```
"im = Image.composite(p, im, "RGBA")"    # Am I using right?
```

p and im was two open Image object open by API "PIL.Image.open(fp, mode='r')"

```
File "GA_engine.py", line 187, in test_create
    im = Image.composite(p, im, "RGBA")
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2313, in composite
    image.paste(image1, None, mask)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1313, in paste
    mask.load()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load'
```

Comment: As the error message says, `mask` is a string. You need to load the mask and create an `Image` from it before trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unclear what you mean by "fix" the images, but it looks like you're trying to combine them in some way.  I can't say if you're using the right tool, since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I can say that you're not using the tool correctly:

If you read [the docs for Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html), you'll see that `Image.composite` requires, as the third argument, another image to use as a transparency mask.

So in place of "RGBA", you need to supply another Image object of the same size as the other two.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: sorry for my bad expression. But what I want is just to mix the color.However I rise another question and got the answer.Anyway thank you and sorry for my bad Eng again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018134/how-to-create-a-triangle-filled-in-a-translucent-color-by-python-pillowfork-pil     I got answer here