# how to create a triangle filled in a translucent color by python pillow(fork PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
im = Image.new('RGB', (255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon([(0, 0), (0, 255), (255, 255), (255, 0)], fill = 'white')
draw.polygon([(1,1), (20, 100), (100,20)], fill = (200, 0, 0)) # outline='red', fill='blue'
im.save('my_pic.png')
```

I know how to create triangle and fill some RGB color in it.
But I do not know how to fill rGBA color into it. (or other translucent color size)

And on the other side ,if I can create first triangle with a translucent color ,when I draw second one, the second one can or can not mix the color with first triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two images and use `alpha_composite` to merge them:

```
img1 = Image.new('RGBA', (255, 255)) # Use RGBA
img2 = Image.new('RGBA', (255, 255)) # Use RGBA
draw1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img1)
draw2 = ImageDraw.Draw(img2)

draw1.polygon([(0, 0), (0, 255), (255, 255), (255, 0)], fill = (255,255,255,255))

transparence = 100 # Define transparency for the triangle.
draw2.polygon([(1,1), (20, 100), (100,20)], fill = (200, 0, 0, transparence))

img = Image.alpha_composite(img1, img2)
img.save("my_pic.png", 'PNG')
```

Transparency can always be set with the 4th value of a color, for example:

- color = (0, 0, 0, 255) => Black color without transparency.
- color = (255, 255, 255, 0) => White color and full transparency.

Comment: But when I draw second triangle ,the second triangle will cover the first one rather than mix the color on the common place

Comment: That's exactly what I want ! Thank you for your answer and patience!